# How to count total selected files on AjaxFileUpload on change java script

Tags: asp.net, jsajaxfileuploader

Greetings!!

I am trying to count total numbers of files have been selected or dropped in file dropbox in AjaxFileUpload controller. It shows on number of files in Queue. I need to access the numbers of files in queue. How could I do that. I am trying to write onchange event for AjaxFileUpload but it's not working which works for ASP File Uploder.

It will be helpful if I get the number of files have been selected on AjaxFileUpload change.

Thanks

Comment: In code behind....I want to get the count of all images in the queue waiting to be uploaded....protected void ajaxUploadImage_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {

Comment: @john wat actually you need on upload complete

Comment: @Sultan can you share the code that you tried. so we can get clear idea what are you trying to do !

Answer (score 3):

You can `count` number of file uploaded successfully from `JavaScript` by using `OnClientUploadComplete` event. Please check below:

AjaxFileUpload Code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadcomplete" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" Mode="Auto" runat="server" />
```

JavaScript Ccode:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var totalUploaded = 0; 
    function uploadcomplete()  
    {  
        totalUploaded += 1;
    }  
</script>
```

For more details about this, please check [AJAX Control Toolkit Tutorial: AjaxFileUpload](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorial-ajaxfileupload-part-three/).

Answer (score 1):

As for my understanding:
AjaxFileUpload.js library doesn't support multiple uploads by itself. So you have to implement the multi-file upload by yourself. There are others libraries that support multiple files upload out of the box: [Fine Uploader 5](https://fineuploader.com/) seen to be a nice one.

If you need to use AjaxFileUpload you can follow this stackoverflow question that is related of what you want to do [upload multiple files with ajaxFileUpload with different file ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521232/upload-multiple-files-with-ajaxfileupload-with-different-file-ids)
. Then you can add a counter for as many times as you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "UploadComplete"  event to do this

```
   protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
                {
                   HttpFileCollection uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
                    int NoOfFiles = uploads.Count
    }
```